# How to get the iterator for a successful binary_search?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, binary-search

I want to get the iterator for the element I'm testing for in `binary-search`. But it only returns a `bool` indicating whether it found the value or not. How to get the iterator?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You want either [lower_bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound), [upper_bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound), or [equal_range](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal_range).

Comment: I'm curious if ```std::lower_bound``` can find  occurrences from right to left? such as ```std::find (container.rbegin(), container.end(), target);```

Comment: @IonutAlexandru You shouldn't pair rbegin with end, you should use rbegin and rend. You also need to be really careful--in general, reversing a sorted container doesn't result in a sorted container unless you invert the less-than operator as well, which means your lower_bound will need a custom comparison function.